# How to work a counter that ends a certain day and restarts the count on another day (CountDown)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, countdown

**how are you**
**I like to do an event every Sunday of the year at 10:00:00 AM**
**It works one time.**

**Example: A countdown timer ends on Saturday, and on Sunday at 10:00:00, i** **restarts itself automatically at ten o'clock (The interval is one day On this interval day I would like to open a gift after the day it closes)**

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 19);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 20);
    if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY) {


        if (cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) == 8) {


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "synday is 8 oclock", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            if (cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) == 19) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "synday is min", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


               resetTimer();


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "synday not  min", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


        } else {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "synday no 8", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    } else {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no sunday", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to schedule the timer reset every Saturday, you can use Android's WorkManager.
It supports every API level so you shouldn't have any issues.
Here is the docs: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

it boils up to this:

import these dependencies

```
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.4.0"
```

Define what you want to do:

```
public class TimerResetWorker extends Worker {
   public TimerResetWorker(@NonNull Context context,@NonNull WorkerParameters params) {
       super(context, params);
   }

   @Override
   public Result doWork() {

     resetTimer(); //do what you want to do

     return Result.success(); //you have Result.failure() / retry() in case something goes wrong
   }
}
```

Then just schedule the job every 7 days (starting from a Saturday):

```
 PeriodicWorkRequest mWork = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(TimerResetWorker.class, 7, TimeUnit.DAYS).build();
 WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(mWork);
```

Comment: How to use obj PeriodicWorkRequest  ???? And where do I put it?

Comment: It's written in the second line...
You use  WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(mWork); to schedule it, and you can put the request wherever you want, I'd suggest MainActivity or if you have Fragments, any relvant one.

Comment: How do I put it in a function ?

Comment: private void resetTimer() {
        mTimeLeftInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
        updateCountDownText();
        startTimer();
    }    how to link this funcation

Comment: Inside doWork() :/

Comment: Please, I do not understand you. Please amend the code and write with clarification

Comment: You should clarify what you want to do, what do you mean with "How do I link this function"? If you want to use that function in the worker just put it in the TimerResetWorker class and call it. Otherwise please explain better.

Comment: I created a class and put your code in it ... and in MainActivity I put the object ,,, inside onCreate What do I do with the configuration

Comment: In MainActivity you should put the last 2 lines of code, PeriodicWorkRequest mWork = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(TimerResetWorker.class, 7, TimeUnit.DAYS).build();
 WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(mWork); (you should execute these 2 lines on a Saturday, maybe check with the calendar, because doWork is called every 7 days)